# Python console double enter doesn't work everytime to start the loop

Tags: python

After the loop is done I use double enter to start it. It works for this example:

```
>>> for i in range(0,100):
...     print i
```

But I can't double enter when it comes to this one (a code sample I am studying for pentesting.). It just starts a new line with no triple dots.

```
>>> import socket
>>> sniff = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 3)
>>> sniff.bind(("eth0", 0x0003))
>>> ap_list =[]
>>> while True :
...     fm = sniff.recvfrom(6000)
...     fm= fm1[0]
...     if fm[26] == "\x80" :
...             if fm[36:42] not in ap_list:
...                     ap_list.append(fm[36:42])
...                     a =  ord(fm[63])
...                     print "SSID -> ",fm[64:64 +a],"-- BSSID ->", \
... fm[36:42].encode('hex'),"-- Channel -> ", ord(fm[64 +a+12])
```

Edit: I'm using Linux(Xubuntu 14.04).

Comment: That’s strange, I can’t reproduce that. I don’t know, what happens if you press Enter again?

Comment: cannot reproduce your effect. Perhaps you've forgotten some closing paren in one of your tests.

Comment: Probably `recvfrom` is just blocking.

Comment: @Daniel I pasted my own code here.

Comment: @kirelagin I actually pressed Enter more then 20 times. It just gives me empty new line. (without 3 dots.)

Comment: If there's nothing to print, the `while` loop will continue indefinitely without giving you a prompt.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it is possible that I have no output, I will make sure to try same script with output. I will inform you.

Comment: @zahedae Then I have to agree with @cdonts, probably `recvfrom` is blocking.